# Give wp-admin access for shop managers

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles

I setup some new roles for shop-managers in my woocommerce shop but i have no idea how to enable access to wordpress dashboard.

I created new options for it but i cant find anything to enable the wp-admin access.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logged in users have access to wp-admin by default, so you must have some other settings in a plugin or theme that is not allowing access. Do you have any membership or user manager plugins installed? If so, check the setting for allowing/disallowing wp-admin access.